# Python: IndexError: list index out of range: Unable to figure out issue

Tags: python-3.x, replace, strip

```
string= "1110 Boston Road\nBronx, NY 10456\n(40.8276026690005, -73.90447525699966)"
```

I want to extract the value -73.90447525699966 out of the above string.

Code:

```
coordinates=re.findall("\(.+\)",string)
lat=string[0].split(",")[1].replace(")","").strip()
```

> Error: IndexError: list index out of range

When I am extracting the value 40.8276026690005 with a similar function(mentioned below), it works fine.

```
coordinates=re.findall("\(.+\)",string)
lat=coordinates[0].split(',')[0].replace('(','')
```

Please help.

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to know more about asking and formatting questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression which doesn't capture the brackets, and then unpacking into variables is very simple:

```
coordinates = re.search('\((.+)\)', string).group(1)
lat, long = (float(c.strip()) for c in coordinates.split(','))
```

gives:

```
>>> lat
40.8276026690005
>>> long
-73.90447525699966
```

Comment: Please accept this answer then (grey --> green tick). Thank you :)

Comment: Done. Thank you:).